# Need help saving action object using django-activity stream

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-contenttypes, django-activity-stream

I am trying to create a newsfeed using django activity stream. I am making a target stream but action object is not saved if it is a comment it does not save

```
 "id": 14,
        "actor": {
            "id": 1,
            "email": "zacmwangi94@gmail.com",
            "first_name": "",
            "last_name": ""
        },
        "verb": "commented on",
        "action_object": null,
        "target": {
            "id": 6,
            "venue": {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "IMAX",
                "address": "NAIROBI",
                "city": "NAIROBI",
                "rating": "1.1"
            },
            "thumbnail": null,
            "user": 1,
            "event_pic_url": null,
            "name": "A movie",
            "time": "2017-11-11T16:02:00Z",
            "description": "A description",
            "event_type": "Movie",
            "invite_only": true,
            "free": false,
            "age_restriction": true,
            "ticket_price": 1000.0,
            "created_at": "2017-03-19T10:35:41.723753Z"
        }
    }
```

When the action object is a photo it is saved properly. This my comment model:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    text = models.TextField()
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

and this is how I create an action after the comment is created:

```
def comment_activity(sender, instance,created, **kwargs):
    if created:
       action.send(instance.user, verb='commented on', action_object=instance, target=instance.content_object)


post_save.connect(comment_activity, sender=Comment, dispatch_uid=comment_activity)
```

I have also tried saving it in the views using the `action.send` signals and `Action.objects.create()` but all these approaches have failed.

```
  def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            comment = Comment.objects.create(**serializer.validated_data)
            Action.objects.create(actor=comment.user,action_object=comment,verb="commented on",target=comment.content_object)
           # action.send(request.user,action_object=comment,verb="commented on",target=comment.content_object)
            return Response(
            serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED
            )
        return Response({
            'status': 'Bad request',
            'message': 'Comment could not be created with received data.'
        }, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Does the problem have to do with the usage of content types and if it does how do I fix it?

I have tried setting `FETCH_RELATIONS` to false but it doesn't change anything.